# Must I build in order to get rid of error in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse

Is there a setting I can change s/t Eclipse will auto-correct its error warning system when I fix the error without having to build the project? For instance, in the following code I have left a semicolon out of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using String = std::string;

class Entity
{
private:
    String my_Name;
public:
    Entity() : my_Name("new name"){}
    Entity(const String& name) : my_Name(name){}

    const String& GetName() const {return my_Name;}
};

int main()
{
    std::cin.get()
}
```

The Eclipse IDE will underline the following line: std::cin.get() in red and highlights it in gray. This is all well and good but if I simply add a semicolon the error highlighting and underlining doesn't go away; not until I build the program does it go away.

So is there a setting I can change somewhere so that I do not have to build the project for that error highlighting and underlining to go away?

Note: Maybe this is just a fluke? It doesn't seem to do this with every error.

Comment: Personal opinion: That error list is nigh useless. Use the build console instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You can clear the errors from the "Problems" window at the bottom. If it is not open you can open it using `Window -> Show View -> Problems`. If you want to clear the errors, *right-click* on the `Errors` (or `Warnings`) in the `Problems` view and select "delete" to make them go away.

Comment: Manual cleanup of Problems is definitely not required for such a simple problem. It is typically used to unlist problems from the projects one is not working on right now.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this answer when it is 100% correct? Can you post your reasoning please?

Comment: @VTT So you downvoted a *correct* answer just because you prefer a different method?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is not correct. It does make warning disappear, but it is not really a solution. Why would you even consider suggesting performing manual cleanup for such a minor problem? It would be extremely incontinent to jump into Problems window and clear it every time after such a common typo happens.

Comment: @VTT The errors persist until you either rebuild or manually clear them. If you edit the file sufficiently then (I think) they can disappear on their own. But if they don't you have no choice.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not getting the stated behavior, the underline for `std::cin.get()` disappears almost immediately after adding a semicolon without even saving file or messing with the `Problems` window. Anyway, you may want to check the following Eclipse settings tab:

> C/C++ -> Editor -> Scalability (especially `Disable Editor life parsing`)
>
> C/C++ -> Editor -> Indexer